# Why isn't there a 'Desktop' folder in my gitbash directory?

Tags: git, directory

I have assignment's for class that require me locate the 'Desktop' folder in my directory, yet, I don't have one. I've tried creating a folder named Desktop but it di not appear when I typed ls; I believe it may be because there is a desktop folder located in OneDrive and thta this is causing the problem..please help.[ScreenOfBash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ8zP.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: On Windows (you're on Windows, but this is true on mac as well) it's usually unwise to *use* the `Desktop` directory, if it exists, to store Git repositories. So if you have an assignment that *requires* that you make this mistake, well, you'll have to go ahead and make this mistake. Just remember that it *is* usually a mistake. Don't do it for real projects.

Comment: The *reason* it's unwise is that the desktop, if it exists, may be cloud-synced, and cloud-synced directories do not play well with Git (nor vice versa). Repositories become corrupted over time. OneDrive itself is an example of a cloud-synced service that should never be used with Git.